# CakePHP: How to control the structure of data returned by find() method

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my `TestsController.php` I'm using the `find()` method...

```
$r = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions ));
```

...and the resulting data looks like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Question' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'created' => '2013-02-13 14:15:16',
            'modified' => '2013-04-18 09:10:03'
        ),
    ), ...
```

Notice how each item in the array is wrapped inside *another* array. I'd like to make the structure of that array consistent with how I'm using it elsewhere so that it will play nicely with elements and other code which expect the structure to match when I set variables inside the controller...

```
$question = $this->Question->findById($id);
$this->set('question', $question);
```

...which results in this:

```
array(
    'Question' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'created' => '2013-04-04 15:25:54',
        'modified' => '2013-04-04 15:25:54'
    ), ...
```

The only differences I'm aware of are that the second example users the `findById()` method, and it's also maybe relevant that the `find()` in the first example is inside a different Model's controller.

**Is there a way to make them match?**

(I know I could manually re-shuffle the data with `array_map()` but I would rather understand why they are different and not have to.)

Comment: you can create your own data retrieval method.. can you consider that as option?

Comment: If it comes to that it's probably simpler for me to just `array_map()` the data into the format I want. Plus, my main goal is to understand/control the different behavior, rather than to think of a work-around (of which there are many).

Comment: This is thoroughly explained in the CakePHP book:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but I've read that chapter 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dave said, it's natural to have numbered arrays when expecting multiple records, as with find('list'), find('all')... well, everyone except find('first').
It's just a matter of knowing what type of records you are expecting to get.

However, if you are decided to change that functionality and to have every record as numbered arrays to make it consistent, there's a way to do that changing just one file.

In your AppModel

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    if(!Set::numeric(array_keys($results)) {
        $results= array($results);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

That way, all your find() methods will return

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Question' => array( /*data*/ ),
), ...
```

even if it's just one record.

*Warning*: I haven't tried this in the AppModel, just in specific cases, so test the functionality and keep adjusting that code until every case is covered. Some things that might produce errors: `$results` with no results, and when retrieving associated data from other model. So watch out because that function isn't definitive and you have to play with it a bit (probably)

Answer (score 1):

When you use find, it expects multiple results, when you use findById, it expects one.  Naturally, the first method returns an array of arrays, so you can iterate over each item.  If you only expect to get one item back, then you should be able to just do:

```
$r = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions ));
$r = $r[0];
```

If you are on a newer version of PHP you can even do:

```
$r = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions ))[0];
```

Comment: Did you mean to say findbyId in your first sentence?